# Angular - multiple themes in Angular Project

Tags: angular

I am working on a project using Angular 7. In the project, I have two themes.

1. AdminLTE
2. LandingTheme

I am using **LandingTheme** as my landing page and **AdminLTE** for the other parts

In my assets folder I put each of the theme's folder there.
 For AdminLTE, I put the javascript in angular.json

```html
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js",
              "src/assets/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js",
              "src/assets/dist/js/adminlte.min.js",
              "src/assets/bower_components/jquery-sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js",
              "src/assets/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
              "src/assets/bower_components/chart.js/Chart.js"    

            ],
```

and the style in styles.scss

```html
@import url(assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css);
@import url(assets/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url(assets/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css);
@import url(assets/bower_components/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css);
@import url(assets/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css);
@import url(assets/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css);
@import url(assets/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css);
```

The question is, how do I do that of LandingTheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use different `.css` files in different parts of Angular app you should include them in your components rather than your root `style.scss`. For example

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-root',
  templateUrl: './landing-root.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Landing.min.css'],
})
export class LandingRootComponent {
}
```

and

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-root',
  templateUrl: './admin-root.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./AdminLTE.min.css'],
})
export class LandingRootComponent {
}
```

Obviously change the paths and components accordingly.

Comment: Not just one css. It has several css and several javascripts

Comment: That's fine, the styleUrls accepts an array of css files. As for the javascripts there shouldn't be any issue including all your libraries at the root level. If there is then you need to get the functionality moved into your Angular components, or find the equivalent Angular modules.

Comment: Can you give me a sample of how to add array of css